# Filling polygons with patterns in Carto using polygon-pattern-file?

Tags: carto, cartocss

I'm trying to create a layer in Carto with three categories of transparent hatching of different colors.

I understand how to use the polygon-pattern-file Carto CSS style but am wondering where I can access existing patterns or how to upload my own patterns. It seems like you can't upload .png's to Carto and I can't figure out where else you are supposed to host them in order to get URL's.

I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

CARTO does not provide a collection of existing pattern, you have two options:

- Use external urls: they have to be publicly available and stable
- Upload you own patterns: you need to use the `IMG` button on a point layer, that interface allows you to upload your own images, so then you can get the final URL and use it in your own polygon layer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! So I have to add the image using a point layer and then use the url once it's uploaded? How do I get that url?

Comment: that's the best approach because that way your asset is in CARTO servers and the access is more reliable. In the past, we've seen issues with external URLs that change over time and break maps. Sorry, I should have disclaimed I work at CARTO :-)

Comment: Hi Jorge, thanks for the help! But once I upload the image in Carto how do I access it? For example, what URL do I set the polygon fill to?

Comment: try to use the image on a point dataset and switch to the `CartoCSS` view of your style to get the url on the code generated by BUILDER.